# R delete rows with least count based on multiple rows

Tags: r

I have the below dataset:

```
   Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4
1 Rank 1 Sub 1     0   10
2 Rank 1 Sub 1     0   20
3 Rank 2 Sub 2     0   30
4 Rank 1     0 Sub 1   40
5 Rank 2 Sub 2     0   50
6 Rank 2     0 Sub 2   10
```

I want to remove the rows that have the least values based on Var2 and Var3. For example, Rank 1 (in Var1) has 2 values in Var2 and 1 value in Var3. I want to remove all entries of Rank 1 that have a value in Var3 and keep all entries that have a value in Var2. The same applies for all other Var1 values.

So the final result will be:

```
       Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4
    1 Rank 1 Sub 1     0   10
    2 Rank 1 Sub 1     0   20
    3 Rank 2 Sub 2     0   30
    4 Rank 2 Sub 2     0   50
```

Is there a way to do that? find the code to build the above table below:

```
Var1 = c("Rank 1", "Rank 1", "Rank 2", "Rank 1", "Rank 2")
Var2 = c("Sub 1", "Sub 1", "Sub 2","0", "Sub 2")
Var3 = c(0, "Sub 1", 0, "Sub 1", "0" )
Var4 = c(10,20, 30, 40,50)
df <- data.frame(Var1,Var2,Var3,Var4)
```

PS: This will be a very large dataset with multiple entries in both Var2 and Var3

Thanks

Comment: So for every `Var1` you want to keep those values which has more non zero values in `Var2` or `Var3`?

Comment: Hi Ronak, yes that is correct!

Comment: @AndreasAvgousti It seems that the you have shown in beginning and the data created as `data.frame` are not same. One got 6 rows and another got 5 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dplyr` package to group on `Var1` to count non-zero values for both `Var2` and `Var3` columns.  Based on the which count is greater, the `filter` criteria can be applied on respective columns. The `case_when` will make logic simpler and cleaner.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  group_by(Var1) %>% 
  filter( case_when(
    sum(Var2 != "0") >= sum(Var3 != "0") ~ Var2 != "0",
    sum(Var2 != "0") < sum(Var3 != "0") ~ Var3 != "0"
      ))
    # # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups: Var1 [2]
# Var1   Var2  Var3   Var4
# <chr>  <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1 Rank 1 Sub 1 0        10
# 2 Rank 1 Sub 1 0        20
# 3 Rank 2 Sub 2 0        30
# 4 Rank 2 Sub 2 0        50
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Var1  Var2  Var3 Var4
1 'Rank 1' 'Sub 1'     0   10
2 'Rank 1' 'Sub 1'     0   20
3 'Rank 2' 'Sub 2'     0   30
4 'Rank 1'     0 'Sub 1'   40
5 'Rank 2' 'Sub 2'     0   50
6 'Rank 2'     0 'Sub 2'   10",
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```